# Node setup to access ID masks in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, id-mask

In the compositor, there is a dedicated ID mask node where you put in the number of the mask you want, and it will output it.

We can get access to ID masks in Cycles materials via the Object Info node, but there is no dedicated ID mask node. I assume it is possible to make something similar with some combination of math nodes and group it up. Has anyone figured out the best way to handle this?

Comment: Aren't masks the product of rendering? How can you access the result of the rendering process prior to generating an image? That would be impossible and create a dependency loop. Also you can access *ID Indexes* in Cycles materials, not *ID Masks*

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You are correct, I mean ID Indexes.

Comment: The mask from the object id is the entire object, meaning any ray that hits the object which is affected by the material you are working with. You could use a math greater/less than node to vary based on id.